# How can I solve this error? "export 'default' (imported as 'App') was not found in './App' (possible exports: App)" (im using react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

heyyy. i wanted to try out react with [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMagNcngvcU&list=RDCMUCmXmlB4-HJytD7wek0Uo97A&start_radio=1&t=749s) tutorial.

at the moment I have only made the data structure. unfortunately i always get an error when compiling.

---

**Error**

```
Compile failed.

Attempted import error: './App' does not contain default export (imported as 'App').
Assets by state 1.6 MiB [cached] 2 assets
Assets by path . 930 bytes
  asset index.html 658 bytes [emitted]
  asset-manifest.json 272 bytes [emitted]
cached modules 1.39 MiB (javascript) 1 bytes (asset) 28.1 KiB (runtime) [cached] 144 modules
./src/index.js 1.34 KiB [built]

ERROR in ./src/index.js 8:38-41
export 'default' (imported as 'App') was not found in './App' (possible exports: App)

webpack 5.66.0 compiles with 1 error in 63 ms
```

---

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react'

import { Footer, Blog, Possibility, Features, WhatWELOVEU, Header } from './containers';
import { CTA, Brand, Navbar } from './components';

export const App = () => {
    return (
        <div className='App'>
            <div className='gradient_bg'>
                <Navbar />
                <Header />
            </div>
            <Brand />
            <WhatWELOVEU />
            <Features />
            <Possibility />
            <CTA />
            <Blog />
            <Footer />

            
        </div>
    )
}
```

---

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

---

these two files are in the "src" folder. in the "src" folder there are also the components and containers. everything is described in the tutorial and the data structure is the same.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjnpN.png)

---

In the folder components and container are .jsx and css files. all css FIles nid empty, in the jsx files you can find the same code always adapted to the name of the file.

p.ex.
**Article.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import './article.css';

const Article = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            Article
        </div>
    )
}

export default Article
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lZw1.png)

---

In containers and components are also index files.

**components/index.js**

```
export { default as Article } from './article/Article';
export { default as Brand } from './brand/Brand';
export { default as CTA } from './cta/CTA';
export { default as Feature } from './feature/Feature';
export { default as Navbar } from './navbar/Navbar';
```

**containers/index.js**

```
export { default as Blog } from './blog/Blog';
export { default as Features } from './features/Features';
export { default as Footer } from './footer/Footer';
export { default as Header } from './header/Header';
export { default as Possibility } from './possibility/Possibility';
export { default as WhatWELOVEU } from './whatWELOVEU/whatWELOVEU';
```

Comment: Try `export default const App`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this in you `index.js`

```
import { App } from './App'
```

or you could change in your `App.js` to this

```
import React from 'react'

import { Footer, Blog, Possibility, Features, WhatWELOVEU, Header 
} from './containers';
import { CTA, Brand, Navbar } from './components';

export default const App = () => {
    return (
        <div className='App'>
            <div className='gradient_bg'>
                <Navbar />
                <Header />
            </div>
            <Brand />
            <WhatWELOVEU />
            <Features />
            <Possibility />
            <CTA />
            <Blog />
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Two options. Choose one.
Hopefully can help you.

Comment: Can you checklist the answer to help the others?

Comment: ye sure i can do it